# Erro no javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: php, javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho um código que muda o valor no banco de 0 para 1 ou vice-versa, em 80% dos casos ele consegue realizar a mudança mas algumas vezes da esse erro `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` e eu já tentei ver a parte do banco e não encontrei nada de errado

JS

```
function enviaAssociado(CTITULAR) {
if(CTITULAR){
    $("#CTITULAR").remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php_action/enviaAssociado.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {CTITULAR : CTITULAR},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
            manageTable.ajax.reload();
            //$("#CTITULAR").val(response.CTITULAR);
        }
           });
    }
    manageTable.ajax.reload();
}
```

PHP

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_connect.php';
if($_POST) {

    $CTITULAR = $_POST['CTITULAR'];


    $sql = "    UPDATE importsmiles4e.tb_conv
    SET    STAT = CASE
         WHEN  STAT = 1 THEN 0
         WHEN  STAT = 0 THEN 1
         ELSE STAT
       END
    WHERE  substring(CTITULAR,2,6) = '$CTITULAR'";
    $query = $connect->query($sql);

    $CTITULAR = $_POST['CTITULAR'];


    $sql = "    UPDATE importsmiles4e.tb_conv3
    SET    STAT = CASE
         WHEN  STAT = 1 THEN 0
         WHEN  STAT = 0 THEN 1
         ELSE STAT
       END
    WHERE  substring(CTITULAR,2,6) = '$CTITULAR'";
    $query = $connect->query($sql);



    $connect->close();


}
?>
```

Comment: Poderia por gentileza passar todo o erro que é gerado no TrackTrace da IDE?

Comment: Na IDE tudo está normal, tanto que na maioria dos casos funciona. Só tenho o que o console do Chrome acusa quando dá erro.

Comment: @MarcosFalcao esta vendo do lado direito escrito `index.php:1`, clique ai e você será levado direto ao código e a linha do erro, e me informe.

Comment: Onde vc está retornando o JSON no PHP? No seu código PHP não mostra nada.

Comment: Você verificou o valor de CTITULAR quando o erro ocorre?  Não será algum problema de parser?

Comment: O valor retornado quando da erro é o mesmo que quando não da, o formato no caso.

Comment: @Sam Desculpe não informei.

Comment: Tá confuso isso. O que o index.php tem a ver com o problema? No seu Ajax vc tá chamando o `enviaAssociado.php` e está esperando um JSON  com `dataType: 'json',`, ou seja, o arquivo `enviaAssociado.php` é **obrigado** a devolver um JSON, caso contrário nem vai entrar no `success`. Só que no código PHP que vc colocou na pergunta (imagino que seja o `enviaAssociado.php`) não está retornando nada, apenas fazendo operações no banco de dados. Mas o que não ficou claro é onde o index.php entra nisso pra dar erro nele.

Comment: eu postei o que o Envia retorna mas ficou bugado, e só saiu o print do index, https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhsDh.png e quando dá certo sempre retorna algo no mesmo formato.

Comment: Mostre o código referente à imagem, como vc tá chamando a função.

Comment: @Sam https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMXP0.png